# why does Comm or Putty doesnt recognize COM1 or any COM for my FDTI cable

Tags: drivers, com

When I try and run COMM program with my as shown bellow it says that I don't have anything in COM1 although in location it says that my cable is at port0001 as shown bellow.

I have installed the FDTI VCP driver but still none of the programs recognise COM1.

Where did I go wrong?

> [image]

> [image: ![enter image description here]

L[image]

Comment: does windows device manager show a com1 port?

Comment: Yes,i even changed its name from COM1 to COM2 with an utility,still both programs not recognising it

Comment: so you have a USB to COM converter? in the past I have worked with some, not all worked well. check the output of `chgport` from CLI

Comment: With what programm do you recomment me send data?
both putty nor COMM gives me the same error.
What is chgport and CLI?
Thanks